# ¿Porque este error: required java.lang.string found int (Android Studio)?

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

Tengo una tabla en sqlite con un campo integer llamado `Tipo`, sucede que de acuerdo al numero de tipo se mostrarán ciertas opciones al usuario, así que hice un `switch` pero me marca el error en el número de los `case` del `switch`:

> "Incompatible types, required java.lang.String, found int"

y no comprendo porque.

```html
private conexion con;
Context context;
SQLiteDatabase bd;

//inicializar
con=new conexion(context,"bd_SQLITE",null,1);
bd= con.getWritableDatabase();

//metodo para consultar
Cursor c = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Tablasql", null);

if(c!=null)
 {
 switch (Tablasql.Tipo){
 case 1: 
 nota =  "Persona1: "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Nombre"));
 nota =  "Telefono: +c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Telefono"));
    break; 
    
 case 2: 
 nota =  "Persona2: "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Nombre"));
 nota =  "Telefono: +c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Telefono"));
    break; 
}   
c.close();
bd.close();
```

Aclaro que en el switch donde pongo Tablasql.Tipo es:

```html
public class Inicio_Detalle_Caso {
    public static final String Tablasql="Tablasql";
    public static final String id="id";
    public static final String Telefono="Telefono";
    public static final String Nombre="Nombre";
     public static final String Tipo="Tipo";
    

    public static final String creart="create table Tablasql"+Tablasql+"("+id+" integer, "+Telefono+" text, "+
            Nombre+" text, "+Tipo+" integer)";
}
```

Comment: Como es que estas trayendo la data de sqlite?

Comment: @LeviArista he modificado el codigo de mi pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás obteniendo `Tipo` de manera incorrecta, deberías traerlo usando tu cursor:

```
c.getInt("Tipo")
```

Finalmente tu `switch` quedaría asi:

```
if(c!=null)
 {
 switch (c.getInt("Tipo")){
 case 1: 
 nota =  "Persona1: "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Nombre"));
 nota =  "Telefono: "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Telefono"));
    break; 

 case 2: 
 nota =  "Persona2: "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Nombre"));
 nota =  "Telefono: "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Telefono"));
    break; 
}
```